# Print SQL table with java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I cant print SQL table with JAVA. I think JDBC Connection is not a problem. How can I print table in console??

```
Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";
        String user = "system";
        String pwd = "SSTTaarr00119922";
        ResultSet rs = null;
```

I did drivermanager getconnection.

```
System.out.println("start Connection");
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            System.out.println("Error loading driver:" + e1.toString());
            return;
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            System.out.println("Fail DB Connection:" + e2.toString());
            return;
        }
```

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM dept";
try {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            System.out.println(sql);
 while (rs.next()) {
                String deptno = rs.getString(1);
                String dname = rs.getString(2);
                String Loc = rs.getString(3);

                System.out.println(deptno + dname + Loc);

            }
```

I cant print while func.

Comment: what exactly is the problem? formatting? wrong data? no data? exception?

Comment: Hey welcome to StackOverflow. To help people answer your question please also post the output which you have in yr console.

Comment: @user85421 I made table in SQLPLUS, connection is working. But cant print table values.

Comment: output is

start Connection
Connection Success
SELECT * FROM dept
Success DB Connection and SQL statement Execution

Comment: Do you `catch` any `Exception` in your real code? I mean in the execution of the statement...

Comment: Did you commit the data in SQLplus?

Comment: are you kidding me? you just wrote the same as in question "can't print table values" does NOT describe the problem. To print use something like `System.out.println(deptno)`! **ALWAYS** print the stack trace, add `e1.printStackTrace()` to the `catch` blocks

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are missing the catch in try---catch block. The code below is worked with SQL Server

```java
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

System.out.println("start Connection");
try {
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=xxx;", "yyy", "zzz");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
    System.out.println("Error loading driver:" + e1.toString());
    return;
} catch (Exception e2) {
    System.out.println("Fail DB Connection:" + e2.toString());
    return;
}

String sql = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[User]";
try {
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    System.out.println(sql);
    while (rs.next()) {
        String deptno = rs.getString(1);
        String dname = rs.getString(2);
        String Loc = rs.getString(3);

        System.out.println(deptno + dname + Loc);

    }
} catch (Exception e2) {
    System.out.println("Fail DB Connection:" + e2.toString());
}
```